# Camel Route 'Diagram' sub-tab not showing in HawtIO

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

When viewing the Camel routes in HawtIO, I'm not seeing the 'Diagram' sub tab to show the route visualization.

This issue first cropped up months ago during a Camel version upgrade (not sure which since we've had multiple upgrades) and so I've upgraded and downgraded our version of Camel from 2.1.X, 2.21.X to 2.23.X (currently at 2.22.1) with no changes. What fixes this issue is switching to HawtIO version 2 which shows the camel route diagrams again, but we lose the functionality of other tabs/plugins that we need so we are staying with version 1.5.11.

I expect to see the 'Diagram' sub tab to show when clicking on a route, but it is not visible. Also, even though they are not needed, I'm not seeing the 'Debug' and 'Trace' sub-tabs for Camel routes either. Is this a compatibility issue with HawtIO and the version of Camel or something else? Thank you.

Comment: I suggest to report a ticket at hawtio as this is not really a question that fits SO

Comment: Thank you! I will open an issue at hawtio to see if I can get some more feedback on this problem.